# How can I add objects to a class array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm hoping someone can help me with this, I've been puzzling over it for a few hours now and can't figure it out. Seems like a real easy thing to do. OK, here goes...

I have a class, class A. One of class A’s (private) instance variables is an array of objects of another, related class (class B).

In a static method of class A I have created several objects of class B.  I need to add these objects to Class A’s instance variable array.

I cannot use `this` to directly access the instance variable as I am trapped in a Static class.

How can I add the newly created objects of class B to class A’s instance variable array, in an formal sense of course.

Hope this makes sense and thanks!

Comment: How about showing the code, instead of describing it? And think about it: to add something to a box (an instance of A), you need a box first.

Comment: why are you using a static class?

Comment: What about just passing the object array in the constructor?

Comment: @JB Nizet - Sorry, I cant't - I'll get in trouble posting it publicly!

Comment: Give us an `SSCCE` version of it then. Link http://sscce.org/

Comment: Without code, it's difficult to solve!

Comment: Oh come on! Your boss will fire you for posting your non-compiling hello world class?

Comment: @ imulsion - Unfortunately I absolutely have to use a static class!

Comment: Sounds like you either need to not make the method static, or move to make class A a singleton. 

Edit: if the class must be static, why not make the member array static?

Comment: If the array is an instance variable of class `A`, you need an instance of `A` to even have an array. Your question as stated makes no sense. What do you mean by a "static class"? Is this `A` or `B`? Or do you mean "static method"?

Comment: Is this instance `A` to which you need to add `B`'s a static variable of the class `A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there. As you say, the array is an **instance variable** of class `A`. This means that it's only accessible when you actually have an **instance** of class `A`. So what you need to do is something like this:

```
A a = new A(); // get an A object
System.out.println(a.arrayOfB.length); // access A's array (but see note)
```

**NOTE**: The code above is just the simplest way to do this. However, you shouldn't generally access the array with `a.arrayOfB` directly. Instead, you should define a method in the A class called `getArray()` that would return that array. This is just a Java standard practice.

Comment: Your answer led me to think in terms of `instanceOfA.arrayOfB[count] = objectOfB` And it worked. You sir, are a genius. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the instance of A, whose array you want to add the B's to, to  the static method.

```
public static void staticMethodInA(A instanceOfA, ...) {

    instanceOfA.arrayOfB[0] = new B();

}
```

Comment: Ooo, so close. Thanks all the same!